# openhab MQTT binding supports TLS?

Tags: ssl, mqtt, openhab

I am new to openHAB.I am currently working on MQTT. I need a secure transmition of data so I searched and got a clue on tls on openhab.But unfortunately some link told that openhab MQTT binding does not support TLS.Any idea on this please share me.

This is the link.

http://blog.jensihnow.de/archives/762-How-to-bridge-between-Mosquitto-MQTT-and-AWS-IoT-MQTT-Broker-to-publish-openHAB-Smarthome-data-to-the-Cloud.html

Thank you.